# md5 mysql и md5 php

Tags: php, mysql, md5

MD5 PHP и MD5 MySQL дают разные результаты. Как сделать, чтобы результат был идентичный.
( мне нужно для сравнения таблиц, одна таблица содержит поле поставщик, другая таблица содержит поле `md5(поставщик)` полученный из PHP.)

Знаете, сложно приводить код, но записи  одной таблицы обновляются/ добавляются средствами битрикс. Считайте, что выполняется запрос в базу вида из пхп:

```
$qery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`suppliers`) VALUES (".md5('Поставщик').")) or die(mysql_error());
```

А запрос я хочу проверить так.

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
inner join users2 on users2.id=users.id and users.suppliers=md5(users2.suppliers)
//или
SELECT * FROM users
inner join users2 on users2.id=users.id 
where
users.suppliers=md5(users2.suppliers)
```

Comment: Очевидно что надо использоват один и тот же метод для создания и валидации а не оба .
Хотя похоже что где то есть другие проблемы.

Comment: @RRR возможно у вас проблемы с кодировками, и в базе кодировка не та, что в php. возможно стоит явно указывать кодировку при создании таблиц. Но это сложно так на пальцах оценить

Comment: Не может такого быть? Вы уверены, что вы адекватно сравниваете эти функции? Может кодировки не совпадают?

Comment: приведите (прямо в вопросе) примеры, как вы считаете md5 средствами php и средствами mysql.

Comment: зачем вы вообще храните md5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

скорее всего, разница получается из-за разных кодировок, используемых в php-скрипте и в поле базы данных.

вам нужно получать строку (перед подсчётом `md5()`) ровно в таком виде, как и в вашем php-скрипте.

иллюстрация разных значений функции `md5()` для разных представлений одной и той же строки:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80dca/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (i int);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select md5(cast('поставщик' as char character set utf8))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80dca/4/0)**:

```
| md5(cast('поставщик' as char character set utf8)) |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|                  ea69b28b7b9897928c900b95656461ed |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select md5(cast('поставщик' as char character set cp1251))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80dca/4/1)**:

```
| md5(cast('поставщик' as char character set cp1251)) |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|                    eb367d01a00ff384bd2cd2ccee5d8285 |
```